# Why username and root are missing in linux server after installing tools with conda?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, datascience-anaconda

On the Linux server, I have my username that looks like below:

```
(base) [david@meteor ~]$
```

I tried installing some tools using `conda` with the following:

```
conda install -c bioconda
```

or

```
conda install -c conda-forge
```

Once all tools are installed I don't see my username and root, it looks like this:

```
(base)
```

Can anyone tell me what could be the problem here?

Comment: It seems `conda` is breaking your `PS1` variable. See [this issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11885)  on github.

Answer (score 1):

I have just ecountered the same problem yesterday.
First, you should initialize conda.

```
conda init bash
```

then, you need to source to update the current shell environment or to exit and restart the shell.

Comment: yes I did the same and I see the username.